# Regex words between commas

Tags: java, regex

I have the following types of sentences to filter:

> Citizens of Poland, Sweden, United States require something
>
> Citizens of Poland require something
>
> Citizens of United States require something

I want to separate names of countries and later save them. I've built the following regex mechanism for that.

```
String sentence;
[...]
Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile("(?:Citizens of )? ([A-Z][a-z]+\\s*[A-Z]*[a-z]*) require");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
while (matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

It works perfect for 2 of 3 cases;

1. `Citizens of Poland require something`
2. `Citizens of United States require something`

How can I build a regex pattern to get words if there's more than one?

Comment: You want `Poland, Sweden, United States` in same captured group?

Comment: No, I want them separate

Comment: In your regex, you allowed only 1 space between words. Which means it selects **United States** but not **United Arab Emirates**. It will stop before **Emirates**. If that's what you want. Then try this: `(?:Citizens of )? ([A-Z][a-z]+\s*[A-Z][a-z]*)`

Comment: Is `require something` a static text?

Comment: @anubhava yes, it always occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this regex in Jave with `\G` and a lookahead:

```
(?:^Citizens of|(?!^)\G,) ([A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*)(?=[a-zA-Z, ]*? require something$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY22Cf/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:` Start non-capture group

  - `^Citizens of` Match text `Citizens of` at the start
  - `|` OR
  - `(?!^)\G,` `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. We match a comma after the previous match of a country name
- `)` End non-capture group
- Match a space
- `(` Start capture group
- `[A-Z][a-z]+` Match an uppercase word
- `(?:` Start non-capture group

  - `[A-Z][a-z]+` Match space followed by a word whose first letter is in uppercase
- `)*` End non-capture group. `*` means match 0 or more of this group
- `)` End non-capture group
- `(?=` Start lookahead condition

  - `[a-zA-Z, ]*? require something$` Assert that we have 0 or more alphabets, comma or spaces before matching text `require something`
- `)` End lookahead